# SELECTING from a previous record and using two primary ORDER BY(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

#### users:

```
user_id    user_name     
---------------------

 1          User A
 2          User B
```

#### tracking:

```
user_id     track         
---------------------

 1           no
 2           no
```

#### applications:

```
user_id    date_of_application   date_ended    grade    status    
---------------------------------------------------------------

 1            2011-01-01         2011-02-28     1.0     Ended
 1            2011-02-02         2011-03-28     1.0     Ended
 1            2011-03-03         2011-04-28     (1.5)   Ended

 2            2011-01-01         2011-02-20     2.0     Ended
 2            2011-02-02         2011-03-11     2.5     Ended
 2            2011-03-03         2011-04-28     (1.0)   Ended

 1            2011-05-10              -          -      Pending
 2            2011-05-15              -          -      Pending
```

- note that the table can contain multiple records of the same user as long as all its previous applications have ended (status = ended)
- **user_id** is not unique (applies to the applications table only)
- date is in **yy-mm-dd** format
- **date_ended** and **grade** are only updated the instant the application has ended
- also, I understand that it probably is recommended for 'status' to have its own table, however I would prefer that the above tables are taken as is (minus the typos and significant errors of course)

What I want to accomplish here is to retrieve all rows **WHERE status is 'Pending'** and such that the value for the **grade** column for each of these retrieved rows is the value of the **latest grade** (in other words the row with the **latest date_ended**), (in parenthesis above) where status is 'Ended' for this particular user (or row).

Also, I would need to have the **first 10 rows** of the result to be ORDERed BY **grade ASC**. And have the succeeding rows after that (**11th row up to the final row**) to be ORDERed BY **date_of_application ASC**.

Clearly SQL queries isn't my strongest area so I'm not sure if it's better (or is only possible) to perform those ORDER BY(s) using 2 or more queries. I however prefer this to be done using a single query only.

#### The desired result:

```
user_id   user_name   date_of_application   grade   status   track 
--------------------------------------------------------------------

 1         User A         2011-05-10        (1.5)    Pending    no
 2         User B         2011-05-15        (1.0)    Pending    no
```

*Working code I have so far on my end [minus the possible typos], (and listed are additions to be applied)*:

- latest grade
- ORDER BY grade (first 10), ORDER BY date_of_application (11th up to last row)

Query:

```
SELECT users.user_name,
       t.track,
       a.user_id,
       a.date_of_application,
       a.status,
       (SELECT ae.grade
          FROM applications AS ae
          WHERE ae.status = 'Ended' 
            AND ae.user_id = a.user_id                                                            
         LIMIT 1) AS grade
  FROM users
  JOIN applications AS a ON users.user_id = a.user_id
  JOIN tracking AS t ON users.user_id = t.user_id
 WHERE a.status = 'Pending'
ORDER BY grade ASC
```

Comment: This is basically a repost from an older question posted here. What was wrong with the answers and comments there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably trying to do too much in one query here.

Anyway, if you want something to hurt your eyes:

```
 select a.* from
 (
 SELECT u.user_name,
 a.user_id,
 a.date_of_application,
 td.grade,
 a.status,
 t.track
 FROM users u
 JOIN applications AS a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
 JOIN tracking AS t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
 select ap.user_id,ap.grade 
 from applications ap
 inner join
 (select a.user_id,max(date_ended) as max_ended_date
 from applications a
 where a.status = 'Ended'
 group by a.user_id
 ) md on md.user_id = ap.user_id and ap.date_ended = md.max_ended_date
 ) as td on u.user_id = td.user_id
 WHERE a.status = 'Pending'
 ORDER BY cast(replace(replace(td.grade,'(',''),')','') as decimal(12,2)),u.user_id ASC
 LIMIT 10
 ) a
 WHERE grade is not null
 UNION ALL
 select b.* from
 (
 SELECT u.user_name,
   u.user_id,
   a2.date_of_application,
   td.grade,
   ifnull(a2.status,'No applications yet') as status,
   t2.track
 FROM users u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user_id,date_of_application,status from applications where     status = 'Pending') AS a2 ON u.user_id = a2.user_id
 JOIN tracking AS t2 ON u.user_id = t2.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( 
 select ap.user_id,ap.grade 
 from applications ap
 inner join
  (select a.user_id,max(date_ended) as max_ended_date
  from applications a
  where a.status = 'Ended'
  group by a.user_id
 ) md on md.user_id = ap.user_id and ap.date_ended = md.max_ended_date
 ) as td on u.user_id = td.user_id
 where u.user_id not in (
 select t1.user_id
 from (
 select ap1.user_id,ap1.grade 
  from applications ap1
  inner join
  (select a1.user_id,max(date_ended) as max_ended_date
   from applications a1
   where a1.status = 'Ended'
   group by a1.user_id
  ) md1 on md1.user_id = ap1.user_id and ap1.date_ended = md1.max_ended_date
  order by cast(replace(replace(ap1.grade,'(',''),')','') as decimal(12,2)),md1.user_id asc
  limit 10
  ) as t1
 )
 ORDER BY status desc,a2.date_of_application ASC
 ) b;
```

This does make the following assumptions:

1. There is always only one row for each user_id in the `users` and
   `tracking` table

**EDIT**

To explain this query a bit:

Inline view aliased `a` (aka 'The Top Half') brings back a list of the top 10 users according to their most recent 'ended' grade ascending. Note the following part of the query that strips any brackets from the grade, converts the resulting number to a decimal to 2 decimal places and orders them ascending by grade and then, in case of equal grade scores, by user_id:

```
ORDER BY cast(replace(replace(td.grade,'(',''),')','') as decimal(12,2)),u.user_id ASC
```

Inline view `b` is pretty much the same as inline view `a` except that excludes users that would appear in The Top Half and orders the results by status `DESC` (to move those users with no applications to the bottom of the list) and date of application `ASC`.

Comment: Your first assumption was correct. As for the second one; well, not always, a user gets to have a row in the applications table with status of 'Pending' only when that user actually signs-up for an application. Also kindly note that a user can only have a status of 'Pending' if all other of his applications have 'Ended' OR it's this user's very first application. Likewise, a user is allowed a maximum of only 1 'Pending' application at a time. Does any of my comments require a change to the code you posted? If so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would assist me on this.

Comment: It does a little bit. Have amended the answer to reflect that there might not be a row present in the applications table. All the other stuff should be OK.

Comment: I've just tested your revised code and everything seems to be working as planned, except for one thing; the first 10 rows retrieved have appeared in descending based on grade, and not the required ascending order. I've tried changing the parts of the code containing ASC/DESC but doing so only made the result worse.

Comment: Whoops. Mistake there. Line 24 was the only one that needed changing from `DESC` to `ASC`. Have made the edit.

Comment: My apologies if this is turning to be troublesome already but the change actually made the resulting table a tad worse. I don't think the problem has anything to do with the table values I'm testing the code with since your original code yields the intended result flawlessly (minus the descending grade issue). I've tried all possible combinations of ASC/DESC on the parts of the code that uses 'cast' and the one that uses DESC and DESC (the original combination) gave the better results.

Comment: Ach. My bad again. I changed the `DESC` to `ASC` in the top inline view but neglected to change it in the `NOT EXISTS` sub select (the part that excludes user_ids in the top 10 grades from rows 11 onwards). I have amended it again and tested it (twice) so it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work well for you... To clarify what is going on, you have to start at the inner-most part of the query.  For each user, find the highest "Pending" date (since as you stated, there would only be one), and the last "Ended" class date.  Grouping by user.  This will guarantee one record per user with both calculated up front as a PreQuery.

Next, do a self-join back to the applications table TWICE... once by the user and Last End date, next by user and last pending date.  By doing a LEFT JOIN, if you only have a person with an application and no end, they will be included... likewise, if only a completed class with no more pending application, they too will be included.

Pull the respective columns from those aliased references to get the grade.  While we're at it, by using SQL variables, and using this query's order by Grade DESCENDING will put the best grades from 1-n without respect to the application date.

Finally, take this entire result set and do a special order by... Order by the condition that if the user's rank is less than 11, use its order.  Otherwise, let everyone else have the same "11" value for the first order by portion...  After that, order by the application date.

Small chunks relying on the previous set.  And this one shouldn't make your head hurt, nor does it require any unions

```
select
      QryRank.*
   from
      ( select
            PreQuery.User_ID,
            usr.user_Name,
            trk.Track,
            PreQuery.LastEnded,
            appEnd.Grade,
            PreQuery.LastPend as Date_Of_Application,
            @Rank := @Rank +1 UserRank
         from
            ( select
                  app.user_id,
                  max( if( app.status = "Ended", date_ended, null ) ) as LastEnded,
                  max( if( app.status = "Pending", app.date_of_application, null )) LastPend
               from
                  Applications app
               group by
                  app.user_id ) PreQuery

            LEFT JOIN Applications appEnd
               on PreQuery.User_ID = appEnd.User_ID
              AND PreQuery.LastEnded = appEnd.date_ended

            LEFT JOIN Applications appPend
               on PreQuery.User_ID = appPend.User_ID
               AND PreQuery.LastPend = appPend.date_of_application

            join Users usr   
               on PreQuery.user_id = usr.user_id

            join Tracking trk
               on PreQuery.user_id = trk.user_id,

            ( select @Rank := 0 ) sqlvars

         order by
            appEnd.Grade DESC ) QryRank
    order by
       if( QryRank.UserRank < 11, QryRank.UserRank, 11 ),
       QryRank.Date_Of_Application
```